# How to filter rows in XmlDocument, xmlDocument.LoadXml and xmlDocument.SelectNodes (similar to a where clause)

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have an SQL server table with an XML column (xmlColumn1) that can contain xml data such as below.

```
<!--Row 1--column (xmlColumn1)

<parameters>
    <Category>Business</Category>
    <Region>CCF25F36-B2A7-4790-82A4-7EC5E016C197</Region>
    <CountryId>EC7333E0-7BEE-4913-9973-2FCABE3DA6F0</CountryId>
</parameters>

<!--Row 2--column (xmlColumn1)

<parameters>
    <Category>Politics</Category>
    <Region>CCF25F36-B2A7-4790-82A4-7EC5E016C197</Region>
    <CountryId>EC7333E0-7BEE-4913-9973-2FCABE3DA6F0</CountryId>
</parameters>

<!--Row 3--column (xmlColumn1)

<parameters>
    <Category>Business</Category>
    <Region>CCF25F36-B2A7-4790-82A4-7EC5E016C197</Region>
    <CountryId>EC7333E0-7BEE-4913-9973-2FCABE3DA6F0</CountryId>
</parameters>

<!--Row 4--column (xmlColumn1)

<parameters>
    <Category>Sports</Category>
    <Region>CCF25F36-B2A7-4790-82A4-7EC5E016C197</Region>
    <CountryId>EC7333E0-7BEE-4913-9973-2FCABE3DA6F0</CountryId>
</parameters>
```

I then have an SQL select query similar to the one below:

```
 SELECT Id, xmlColumn1
  FROM MyTable
```

The rows returned by the query above are loaded into a list as below.

```
  List<myData> Data = MyDataSource.GetMyData();
```

I now process this data and add it to another list as below.

```
                if (Data.Count.Count > 0)
                {
                    (Data.ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDocument.LoadXml(x.id);
                        XmlNodeList paramsList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Region");

                        foreach (XmlNode node in paramsList)
                        {
                            MyOtherList.Add(new OtherList { Id = x.Id, Region = new Guid(node.InnerText) });
                        }
                    });
```

How can i add a condition to the above code such that ONLY rows where the XML column parameter `"Category"` is **"Business"** are added to `MyOtherList`.

I don't want to add the rows to `MyOtherList` at `MyOtherList.Add(new OtherList { Id = x.Id, Region = new Guid(node.InnerText) });` if the parameter category is NOT Buiness.

Comment: just to be sure, so you wanted the sql query to see the content xml column's before deciding to load them or not? the dumbest way would be to treat it as string or use [raw query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries). entity framework drops many feature request for xml/json column integration, [#19049](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19049), [#6284](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6284). alternatively do the heavy lifting on application side using xpath or something (like linq's `Where`).

Comment: @BagusTesa What i want to do but i'm struggling with is applying something like " linq's Where" to that code. Any clues on how i can achieve that?